# PHP DOM get children excluding text nodes

Tags: php, xml, dom

How can I get only child nodes without text nodes?
I have the following document:

```xml
<Sys>
    <Const>
        <C1>A</C1>
        <C2>B</C2>
        <C3>C</C3>
    </Const>
</Sys>
```

Getting children of "Const" I get 6 elements,

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($file_path);

$constants = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Const')->item(0);

foreach ($constants->childNodes as $const) {
    echo $const->nodeName . ': ' . $const->nodeValue . '<br />';
}
?>
```

which prints:

```
#text:
C1: A
v#text:
C2: B
#text:
C3: C
```

How can I get the only C1, C2 and C3 nodes, excluding text nodes?

Comment: You need just value of C1 for example?

Comment: `xpath` or check `nodeType`.

Comment: If you are processing a data XML file, you may find it easier to use SimpleXML as it will exclude a lot of the extra content which DOM retains.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I am using DOM for backwards compatibility issues. The libxml module is more likely to be installed than SimpleXml. If you have different evidences, I would be glad to know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example given in question, you can simply set the flag `preserveWhiteSpace` to be false, this prevents the whitespace (new lines, tabs, spaces etc.) from creating extra text nodes...

```
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->load($file_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xpath expressions to fetch specific parts of a DOM.

- Any "Const" element `//Const`
- Child elements of "Const" `//Const/*`

Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<Sys>
    <Const>
        <C1>A</C1>
        <C2>B</C2>
        <C3>C</C3>
    </Const>
</Sys>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//Const/*') as $constant) {
  echo $constant->nodeName . ': ' . $constant->textContent . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
C1: A
C2: B
C3: C
```